# Efficiency + safety: declare new NSArray var, or overwrite existing NSMutableArray with mutableCopy?

Tags: objective-c, performance, nsmutablearray, nsarray, subclass

I need to sort a mutable array, but in this specific case when it comes time to sort, *I don't need it to be mutable anymore.* The `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` method returns an `NSArray *` even when called by an `NSMutableArray *` object. I have 3 options:

**1) I can make a mutableCopy of the returned NSArray * and store it in the var I already have**

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];

// add a bunch of stuff to the array

mutableArray = [[mutableArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] mutableCopy];
```

**2) I can make a new NSArray * var to hold the returned NSArray ***

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];

// add a bunch of stuff to the array

NSArray *array = [mutableArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

**3) I can ignore Xcode's warnings and store the returned NSArray * object in an NSMutableArray * var**

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];

// add a bunch of stuff to the array

mutableArray = [mutableArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

I realize that for most cases the difference is negligible, but considering available resources, efficiency, and safety, which would be the overall "best" option?

**EDIT: I hadn't considered that the best option might be to create a non-mutable array from the mutable one *before* sorting it. Not sure if this would be, in fact, the best option, but something I figured I'd mention.**

Comment: What about `sortUsingSelector:` if you already have a mutable array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a mutable array already, just use the following method on `NSMutableArray`:

```
- (void)sortUsingSelector:(SEL)comparator
```

That way you're not recreating anything. This is likely more efficient than creating a new, sorted array from the original and then creating a mutable copy of that. Part of the point of having a mutable array in the first place is that you can change stuff around without needing to recreate it each time, so sorting is a very obvious thing to have here.

Comment: What makes you sure that it's more efficient? I would bet it's not ;)

Comment: It may not be more efficient than starting with an `NSArray` and using `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` to create a new, sorted `NSArray` (although I think it is very likely it is more efficient, because we're not creating any secondary objects). But I am sure it's more efficient than taking an existing `NSMutableArray`, creating a sorted `NSArray` with `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` and then creating a mutable copy of that.

Comment: Well, the implementation is private, but I would guess that a immutable array has very likely O(1) time complexity for random access, while the chances for a mutable array having O(1) for random access *may* be smaller than 1 - and possibly be O(log n), since a mutable array might be implemented with a different data structure than a vector. That would mean, that sorting a mutable array *might* be slower than sorting the same immutable array. But this is just a "possible" thesis ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper If you consider that he's starting with an `NSMutableArray` in the first place, then calling the `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` method on the mutable array might possibly be slower, perhaps by a significant margin, as compared to calling that same method on a standard `NSArray`, for the very reason you describe (which we don't know anything about, because as you said, it's private implementation). Therefore, `sortUsingSelector:`, being a method specifically designed for `NSMutableArray`, is probably the fastest way of getting an `NSMutableArray` sorted.

Answer (score 0):

The array you get back from `sortedArrayUsingSelector` won't be a deep copy - it will contain the same pointers as the original array, just in a different order. These array methods in foundation will be well optimized, so I wouldn't worry about it too much.

Instead, just decide what you want.  If you *want* a sorted `NSArray *` that won't look like an `NSMutableArray *`, just use `sortedArrayUsingSelector`, which returns an `NSArray *`

If you don't need the original unsorted array anymore, just sort the mutable array, like @Gavin suggests.